# Access 2007 - Current event code not displaying for current record but for next record

Tags: ms-access

I've got an odd problem which I'm hoping someone can shed light on. On a form's Current event I have the following code:

```
Me.lblDateRange.Caption = "Between " & DateAdd("yyyy", -3, Forms!frmContainer.subDiagnosis.Form!txtDateOfDiagnosis) & " and " & Forms!frmContainer.subDiagnosis.Form!txtDateOfDiagnosis & ""
```

Basically the label needs to display the three-year date range that the user must consult. It worked fine at the start but then I started getting an error message. Made some changes, tried different ways of doing it. Now the above code is calculating and displaying a date range without an error message but the dates are always one record off, so the date range showing for record 2 is actually the date range for record 3 and so on. I've tried adding:

```
Me.Repaint
```

after this line but it doesn't make a difference, although if you actually click the Refresh All button on the toolbar the correct date range is displayed. Any ideas how to sort this?

Comment: Try adding the Form.Refresh command before you repaint - see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Nope, and having closed the database down for a while and gone back in, I'm now getting the original 2455 error again: You have entered an expression that has an invalid reference to the property Form/Report.

Comment: Is the form where the label is connected in any way to the form where the date is and are they both bound to tables?  If so, you might try to use a dlookup() function to get your dates.

Comment: @JBL: Thanks so much, using DLookup() from the table instead of using the form control solved the problem. If you want to change your comment to an answer I'll mark it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If the forms are bound to a table, it may be better to use a dlookup function to retrieve your dates.  Dlookup won't run into any problems surrounding the state of a form.